# how to convert numbers to character in mysql while using select query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert numbers to a character representation.

I have a column named salary and it stores a value, e.g. 400 for employee 1. I want to display the salary of employee 1 with a select query. But, if a salary is 200 then display the salary as `*`, and if salary is 400 display `**` and if salary is 600 than display `***`.

So each `*` = 200

Can any one guide me how to do this ?

Comment: Please remove the sql-server tag - sql-server is not the same as mysql.

Comment: what in case of `250` ?

Comment: for 250 just display two stars

Answer (score 0):

If there are a limited number of options (less than maybe 10), you want a case statement - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case.

If you want many many asterisks if someone's salary is 10,000, you could use a little logic around rpad - http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-rpad-function.php.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very trivial problem.

You have tagged it with both mysql and sql-server; these are different tools with different language variations. The answer below will work with mysql but may need some refactoring for sql-server.

```
Select name
, concat(salary,rpad('',floor(salary/200),'*'))
From your table
...
```

Comment: hi your answer is almost near to my question , i just want 1 more thing i want to show just star * instead of intgers means for salary 100 show *** instead of showing 100***

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use [RPAD](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-rpad-function.php)

```
SELECT RPAD('',FLOOR(salary/200), '*') AS stars
FROM table_name
```

And in SQL Server, you can use [REPLICATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx)

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT 200 AS salary
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 400 AS salary
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 600 AS salary
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 200 AS salary
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 200 AS salary
)
SELECT REPLICATE('*', salary/200) AS stars
       ,salary/200 AS salary
FROM C
```

Output

```
stars   salary
*       1
**      2
***     3
*       1
*       1
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server:

```
create table #tab (
            name nvarchar(100),
            salary int
        )
insert #tab values ('Mrs. Garrett', 100), ('Mr. Drummond', 200),
                   ('Kimberly', 300), ('Willis', 400), 
                   ('Arnold', 500), ('Tooty', 600), 
                   ('Natalie', 700)

select  name,
        salary,
        replicate('*', floor(salary/200))
    from #tab

drop table #tab
```

Which produces:

```
name           salary   (No column name)
Mrs. Garrett    100 
Mr. Drummond    200 *
Kimberly        300 *
Willis          400 **
Arnold          500 **
Tooty           600 ***
Natalie         700 ***
```

Alternatively, you could replace the `replicate()` with this:

```
case
    when salary >= 600 then '***'
    when salary >= 400 then '**'
    when salary >= 200 then '*'
    else ''
end
```

Comment: how to this in mysql and i want to produce * for 200 instead of 200* like **** for 800 instead of 800****

Comment: This does that... I'm selecting the salary as well so you can see them.  There are three columns in my results.  just remove the line "salary," from my select statement if you don't want it back.